# What is an appropriate tool for processing JSON Activity Streams for both BI and Hadoop?

Tags: json, hadoop, android-activity, stream, etl

I have a number of systems, most of which are capable of generating data using JSON Activity Streams[1] (or can be coerced into doing so), and I want to use this data for analytics.

I want to use both a traditional SQL datamart for OLAP use, and also to dump the raw JSON data into Hadoop for running batch mapreduce jobs.

I've been reading up on Kafka, Flume, Scribe, S4, Storm and a whole load of other tools but I'm still not sure which is best suited to the task at hand. These seem to be either focussed on logfile data, or real-time processing of the activity stream, whereas I guess I'm more interested in doing ETL on activity streams.

The type of setup I'm thinking of is where I provide a configuration for all the streams I'm interested in (URLs, params, credentials), and the tool periodically polls them, dumps the output in HDFS, and also has a hook for me to process and transform the JSON for insertion into the datamart.

Do any of the existing open-source tools fit this case particularly well?

(In terms of scale I expect a max of 30,000 users interacting with ~10 systems - not simultaneously - so not really "Big Data", but not trivial either.)

Thanks!

[1] http://activitystrea.ms/

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [streamsets.com](http://streamsets.com)

It's an open source tool (and free to use) built exactly for these kinds of use cases.

You can use the HTTP Client source and HDFS destination to achieve your main goals. If you decide you need to use Kafka or Flume as well, support for both are also built-in.

You can also do transformations in a variety of ways including writing python or javascript for more complex transformations (or your own stage in Java if you choose).

You can also check out logstash ([elastic.co](http://elastic.co)) and [NiFi](http://nifi.apache.org) to see if one of those works better for you.

*Full disclosure, I'm an engineer at StreamSets.